# Cannot login using correct password

Tags: server, login, password

I installed Ubuntu server on a PC, with correct user + password.

We installed webmin, and we are running a website on this PC. It works. I can remotely update webmin and ubuntu package.

However, I am facing a serious issue: I cannot log in on a session using user + password.

What happens here: when entering the correct password, the session intends to open for 1sec, screen becomes black as if I enter in the session, but it comes back to the user/password menu, as if my password was wrong.

But I confirm that my password is correctly input as well as user name.

First I though that we made a mistake during installation by defining a wrong password, because of keyboard definition (as we are in Japan), but it seems that the problem is not this one.

So it is still impossible to enter in any session excepted guest session.

However, even I tried to login as admin or root, it does not work too.

So the web site works! I can update remotely ubuntu, but I cannot enter in the session when I am in front of the computer! It is really difficult for me to understand and to recover this strange problem.

Any idea will be really helpful!

Comment: I had the same problem after a disk crash and I had to reinstall my system (which is annoying).

Comment: I also got kicked out after login in this way after replacing my /home/username/ directory with that from another user (stupid, I know now.). Maybe your new program messed around with some vital files in there? I'm just trying to inspire the people with more knowledge coming here, I personally can't help you with this issue. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by a number of reasons, many being explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). It's almost always caused by some misconfiguration (i.e. you've done something wrong).

It also happened to me, and it turned out that I've screwed my `PATH` environment variable, so no command was working. I've done this with a simple mistake in my `~/.profile` file. Instead of putting there:

```
export PATH="$GOROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

I've put:

```
export PATH="$GOROOT/bin"
```

thus removing everything from `PATH` except for `go`. And after rebooting, I've ended up in an infinite login loop.

No matter the actual cause, chances are that you'll be able to login to the shell instead of GUI, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. Once you're in, you can troubleshoot/fix the issue.

I hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and it can be caused by a countless number of things (for me it was a script that ran on login that was crashing). So I cant help with a fix but I can point you to the possible problem.

First take a look at your logs to see what error is causing your account to be logged out straight away.

they should be located in

`var/log/`

or

`/var/log/syslog`

you might be able to access these via your guest account (depending on how you set it up).

you also should be able to read you logs via webmin under

`system > system logs`

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SystemLogs

but it can vary depending on how you setup webmin.